# Access post comment endpoint of Instagram API got rejection

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to develop a Instagram client for iPad.
I had requested to access post comment endpoint to Instagram, but got rejection.
Any one know how to apply to access post comment endpoint ?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

From the Instagram site:

This endpoint is restricted to the following use cases:

- A business requesting rights to media objects from the Instagram Community in order for the media to be used for display outside of Instagram.
- A business providing customer service to members of the Instagram Community by interacting through comments.
- A business responding to members of the Instagram Community that participate in a specific reward or coupon campaign.

Apparently your case is not one of these, so it got rejected.